# How to clear everything on screen?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

ok i know im dumb but i do need help! i dont know how to get rid of those black things on there ( i just downloaded blender so Q-Q)
HELP!

Comment: press A to select everything and then press the delete key (or X) to clear... but why do you want to do that? If you are starting with blender it would be  better if you learned what they are and how you can use the camera and the lights to make your models visible...

Comment: cegaton is right. Without a camera you will not be able to render your object, and without any light your whole scene will be nearly black.

Comment: The bottom grid hasn't cleared.
This clears the Camera, Light and Object.
I need a clear white background for Grease Pencil keyframes, which I'm learning from [How to Sketch Animations in Blender](https://medium.com/hackers-and-makers/how-to-draw-animations-in-blender-f51e98c07647).

Answer (score 2):

The thing with triangular sides is camera. Your final render will be looking through that. You can view it by pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. You should not delete it, because blender might not work as you expect when rendering.

The circular thing is a lamp. All the shadows will be calculated using the orientation and location of the lamp. In the nutshell - you need a lamp to prevent your scene from being completely dark.

You need these things to render your final image, but if you really want to delete these just press <kbd>A</kbd> one or two times to activate them and then press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> key to delete them.